# block user with zkemkeeper.dll

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, time-and-attendance

I am working with biometric device (attendance device) with the sdk support  zkemkeeper.dll

I fetch the attendance from ZKTeco biometric device sucessfully, but when i am trying to block user, the code executes successfully, but the user is able to authenticate in the biometric machine and the door opens.

i tried the following codes to block a user as mentioned in the sdk manual but user is not blocked in the device.

```
 EnableUser = objZkeeper.EnableUser(dwMachineNumber, did, dwEMachineNumber, dwBackupNumber, false);
```

another code used

```
EnableUser = objZkeeper.SSR_EnableUser(dwMachineNumber, did, false);
```

both codes executes with out any error but user is still enabled. please help me on this.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? pretty much the same question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789031/zkteco-zkemkeeper-to-disable-device-until-transaction-is-completed

Comment: @user5173426 no. the block user option is not available in the zk teco machine with model no f18, so it never works. but in some ESSL brand machines it works

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value if true or false. If false, there is a high chance that your scanner doesnt support the enable/disable user.

If you get true, read the objZkeeper.GetLastError([out]). Mostly you would get some error code as listed below:

- -10     Transmitted data length is incorrect
- -5      Data already exists
- -4      Space is not enough
- -3      Error size
- -2      Error in file read/write
- -1      SDK is not initialized and needs to be reconnected
- 0       Data not found or data repeated
- 1       Operation is correct
- 4       Parameter is incorrect
- 101     Error in allocating buffer

Answer (score -3):

```
     bool bIsConnected = objZkeeper.Connect_Net(locationIP, iPortNo); 
     bool ex= objZkeeper.RegEvent(1, 4);
     EnableUser = objZkeeper.SSR_EnableUser(dwMachineNumber, did, false);


     bool prm=objZkeeper( dwMachineNumber,  LONG EventMask);
     EventMask: Code of an event. 
     Values are as follows:
    1 OnAttTransaction, OnAttTransactionEx
    2 (1<<1) OnFinger
    4 (1<<2)OnNewUser
    8 (1<<3) OnEnrollFinger
    16 (1<<4) OnKeyPress
    256 (1<<7)OnVerify
    512 (1<<8)OnFingerFeature
    1024 (1<<9)OnDoor, OnAlarm
    2048 (1<<10)OnHIDNum
    4096 (1<<11)OnWriteCard
    8192 (1<<12)OnEmptyCard
    16384 (1<<13)OnDeleteTemplate


Masks are the controls that enable you to perform operations. You need to use them in the method
```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: Don't post it in the comment, add it to your answer.